# Configure NAT filtring behavior with iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I'm using this rule to configure SNAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 193.49.142.107:4000
```

I want to specify a rule to filter out packets not destined to the internal address and port that initiated the session. Additionally, for receiving packets from a specific external endpoint, it is necessary for the internal endpoint to send packets first to that specific external endpoint's IP address.(NAT Address Dependent Filtering)

Example:

A machine with internal IP and port (X:x) which is behind the NAT opens a connexion to a server with IP Y. So with the rule I must be able to allow only connexion coming from IP address Y and destined to (X:x). All other connexion will be droped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -P FORWARD -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

What do these rules do?

1. `-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE` hides your internal IP's as packets leave your network
2. `-P FORWARD -j DROP` sets the default policy for your FORWARD chain to DROP
3. `-A FORWARD -o eth1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` allows new and established FORWARDed connections out
4. `-A FORWARD -i eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` allows only established FORWARDed connections in

The rules above are assuming that you're using this box as a gateway/firewall with `eth1` connected to your WAN and `eth0` connected to your LAN.

Additional Reading: [Postrouting and IP Masquerading](https://www.centos.org/docs/4/4.5/System_Administration_Guide/postrouting-ipmasquerading.html)

**EDIT**

To configure "conditional" port forwarding:

By source port

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp --sport [trusted_source_port] --dport [external_port] -j DNAT --to [internal_ip]:[internal_port]
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d [internal_ip] --dport [internal_port] -j ACCEPT
```

By source IP

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp -s [trusted_source_ip] --dport [external_port] -j DNAT --to [internal_ip]:[internal_port]
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d [internal_ip] --dport [internal_port] -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think, for a session established from (X:x) to (Y:y), these rules allow only packets comming from IP address and port (Y:y). Isn't there a way to allow packets even with a different port number. I mean, allow machine Y to open new sessions to internal machine X.

Comment: Have you tried this?  The kernel maintains a list of all connections and it + TCP automagically manage IP/Port communication so you don't have to it manually. However, if you want to allow machine Y to establish new connections on internal machine X then you want to configure port forwarding.  Is that correct?

Comment: It's rather Port Triggering. It's similar to port forwarding but with additional conditions. According to my last example only machine Y will be allowed to establish new connexions to the internal machine X. We can say that the condition here is that machine X establishes a connexion to the external machine that will be allowed. I hope I was clear.

Comment: I think the only way to do what I described is to get the IP destination Y for a session established from (X:x) to (Y:y) and then add this rule:
`#iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -s IP –d X’ –dport x’ -j DNAT --to X:x` with X' and x' the external IP and port affected by NAT.

Then at the end of all sessions delete the defined rule.

Now the problem is how to get the connection information.

Comment: See my answer's update

Comment: Thanks for your help. (Note: for the specific case I explained all the parameters in brackets are not static. Which means the NAT machine should get those parameters when a session is established and then add the rule)

Comment: Then you're gonna have to get creative :)  You can look into port knocking with [fwknop](http://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/docs/fwknop-tutorial.html) but I haven't tried it myself.